# How might I extract the property values of a JavaScript object into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Given a JavaScript object:

```
var dataObject = {
   object1: {id: 1, name: "Fred"}, 
   object2: {id: 2, name: "Wilma"}, 
   object3: {id: 3, name: "Pebbles"}
};
```

**How do I efficiently extract the inner objects into an array?**  I do not need to maintain a handle on the *object[n]* IDs.

```
var dataArray = [
    {id: 1, name: "Fred"}, 
    {id: 2, name: "Wilma"}, 
    {id: 3, name: "Pebbles"}]
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
var dataArray = [];
for(var o in dataObject) {
    dataArray.push(dataObject[o]);
}
```

Comment: I assume that he wants to preserve the ordering, so this isn't good enough.

Comment: And what is "ordering" in your opinion?

Comment: If you don't want to include properties from the object's prototype (there *shouldn't* be any if it's a plain object), you can filter them by checking `dataObject.hasOwnProperty(o)`.

Comment: A side note: if for some reason extra properties are added to `Object.prototype` this will break without using `hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: Any reason to use `new Array` here instead of `[]`?

Comment: @SLaks since an object is defined as `an unordered collection of properties` there is no order to preserve.

Answer (score 88):

```
var dataArray = Object.keys(dataObject).map(function(k){return dataObject[k]});
```

Comment: @Qix: You mean so much **faster**?

Comment: @julien No. Not at all. Not even close. Accepted answer is faster in every case always.

Comment: @Qix: And ```for (var o = 0, l = dataObject.length; o < l; o++) {}``` would be even faster than ```for ... in```. Although, map *could* be quicker when the function inside the map is very complicated, and is processed using multiple threads and webworkers... but yes, in *almost* all cases a for loop is much faster.

Comment: This is so much *safer* and *idiomatic*. Object.keys does a `hasOwnProperty` internally.

Comment: Adding a check for `hasOwnProperty` to the accepted answer is efficient than this method where an array is built first and it is traversed O(N) space + O(N) time.

Answer (score 39):

**ES6 version:**

```js
var dataArray = Object.keys(dataObject).map(val => dataObject[val]);
```

Answer (score 33):

Using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#values):

```
var dataArray = _.values(dataObject);
```

Comment: @Veverke Underscore is a very widely used commons library.

Answer (score 16):

With jQuery, you can do it like this -

```
var dataArray = $.map(dataObject,function(v){
     return v;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CPM4M/1/)

Answer (score 15):

ES2017 using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const dataObject = {
    object1: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Fred"
    },
    object2: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Wilma"
    },
    object3: {
        id: 3,
        name: "Pebbles"
    }
};

const valuesOnly = Object.values(dataObject);

console.log(valuesOnly)
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your dataObject is defined the way you specified, you do this:

```
var dataArray = [];
for (var key in dataObject)
    dataArray.push(dataObject[key]);
```

And end up having dataArray populated with inner objects.

Comment: This also doesn't do what he's asking for.

Comment: He wants the objects themselves, not their names.

Comment: In that case, just omit the ".name" in the third line.

Answer (score 7):

Using [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718777/how-might-i-extract-the-property-values-of-a-javascript-object-into-an-array/1718806#1718806) and knowing that [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is proposed in [ECMAScript 2017 Draft](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.values) you can extend Object with method:

```
if(Object.values == null) {
    Object.values = function(obj) {
        var arr, o;
        arr = new Array();
        for(o in obj) { arr.push(obj[o]); }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[Editing and updating my answer. The other answers seem to overlap with mine pretty much, but, I thought I have another ago and provide an alternative].

I present 3 solutions to this problem, based on:

- Object.keys
- Object.values
- Object.entries

Objects.keys() solution:

```js
let keys = Object.keys(dataObject); // ["object1", "object2", "object3" ];
let keysToResult = keys.map( e => dataObject[e] ); // [{"id":1,"name":"Fred"},{"id":2,"name":"Wilma"},{"id":3,"name":"Pebbles"}]
```

Object.values solution:

```
let values = Object.values(dataObject); // [{"id":1,"name":"Fred"},{"id":2,"name":"Wilma"},{"id":3,"name":"Pebbles"}]
```

Object.entries solution:

```
let entries = Object.entries(dataObject); // [["object1",{"id":1,"name":"Fred"}],["object2",{"id":2,"name":Wilma"}],["object3",{"id":3,"name":"Pebbles"}]]
let entriesToResult = entries.map( ([k,v]) => v ); [{"id":1,"name":"Fred"},{"id":2,"name":"Wilma"},{"id":3,"name":"Pebbles"}]
```

All three solutions have their own features.

Object.keys() returns an array with insufficient result. So, we use Array.prototype.map to top up each value in the array to get close to what we want. In general, we can think of Object.keys() combined with map as a mechanism to customize our result list with what we want.

Object.values() is interesting since it discards the key and just returns the results only. In fact, for this problem, this is perfect since the answer requires no further processing.

Object.entries() returns more than what we want since it returns both keys and values. We need to use map to customize our result. In fact, we need to cut out the excess information.

Object.keys(), Object.values() and Object.entries() are all very useful functions which is why I wanted to show all 3 as a solution to this problem. Depending on your specific use case, you may find one to a better fit to solving your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a bit verbose, but robust and fast

```
var result = [];
var keys = Object.keys(myObject);
for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
    result.push(myObject[keys[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Object.values() method is now supported. This will give you an array of values of an object.

```
Object.values(dataObject)
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Comment: Looks like a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case you use d3. you can do `d3.values(dataObject)` which will give

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to destruct object values into array:

`[...Object.values(dataObject)]`

```js
var dataObject = {
   object1: {id: 1, name: "Fred"}, 
   object2: {id: 2, name: "Wilma"}, 
   object3: {id: 3, name: "Pebbles"}
};

var dataArray = [...Object.values(dataObject)];
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
var dataArray = Object.keys(dataObject).map(function(k){return dataObject[k]});
```