# Javascript create 2 arrays from object data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have some data and I need a loop which creates 2 arrays...

So I first create the 2 arrays:

```
namelist = [];
countList = [];


{
    "id": "622",
    "name": "main",
    "sub": {
        "637": {
            "id": "637",
            "name": "name 1",
            "stats": {
                "count": 5
            }
        },
        "638": {
            "id": "638",
            "name": "name 2",
            "stats": {
                "count": 10 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The desired result for this example would be:

For namelist:

```
['name 1', 'name 2']
```

For countList:

```
[5, 10]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a loop that we can try and help you fix? Rather than one of us just solving it for you.

Comment: [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement) + [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How might I extract the property values of a JavaScript object into an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718777/how-might-i-extract-the-property-values-of-a-javascript-object-into-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nameList = [];
var countList = [];

var myObj = 
{
    "id": "622",
    "name": "main",
    "sub": {
        "637": {
            "id": "637",
            "name": "name 1",
            "stats": {
                "count": 5
            }
        },
        "638": {
            "id": "638",
            "name": "name 2",
            "stats": {
                "count": 10 
            }
        }
    }
};



for(var key in myObj.sub){
    nameList.push(myObj.sub[key].name);
    countList.push(myObj.sub[key].stats.count);
}

console.log(nameList);
console.log(countList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var key in obj.sub){
    nameList.push(obj.sub[key].name);
    countList.push(obj.sub[key].stats.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` may help you to walk through object properties. Example related to your object:

```
var namelist = [],
  countList = [],
  obj = {
    "id": "622",
    "name": "main",
    "sub": {
      "637": {
        "id": "637",
        "name": "name 1",
        "stats": {
          "count": 5
        }
      },
      "638": {
        "id": "638",
        "name": "name 2",
        "stats": {
          "count": 10
        }
      }
    }
  };

Object.keys(obj.sub).forEach(function(item) {
    namelist.push(obj.sub[item].name);
    countList.push(obj.sub[item].stats.count);
});

console.log(namelist, countList);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ry0zqweL/

Obviously, you can optimise it in many ways. It's just illustrating one of the many solutions.