# Javascript Convert Object containing arrays into Array containing Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What I have is something like this:

```
arr = {
        a: [array], 
        b: [array], 
        c: [array]
      }
```

... and so on
But it is an object. 
How do I turn it into this:

```
arr = [[array],[array],[array]]
```

... and so on

Comment: Why does the object start at index `1`?

Comment: oh it doesn't.  Sorry.  I guess I could use letters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How might I extract the property values of a JavaScript object into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718777/how-might-i-extract-the-property-values-of-a-javascript-object-into-an-array)

Comment: You do realize that by extracting each property value into an array, you lose the information about the property names in the original object, unless you have a strict sorting criteria.

Comment: yes I don't need them.

Comment: What are your trying to accomplish? There might be a more straight forward way to do wahtever that is

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems a little vague. However, If you are dealing with an Object you can use Object.values() to get an array of values back.

```js
var obj = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [6,7,8,9]};
var arr = Object.values(obj)

console.log(arr);
```

If you are dealing with a Map you can use Array from.

```js
var arr = [
  ['a', [1, 2, 3]],
  ['b', [4, 5, 6]],
  ['c', [6, 7, 8, 9]]
];
arr = Array.from(arr, x => x[1]);
console.log(arr);
```