# Convert a map to an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a map of objects which I want to convert to an array of objects.

The map looks as follows, using each objects id as a key:

```
{
    'a' : {
        id ' a',
        name : 'Andrew'
    },
    'b' : {
        id : 'b',
        name : 'Barry'
    },
    'c' : {
        id: 'c',
        name: 'Caroline'
    }
}
```

and I would like to convert it an an array:

```
[
    {
        id: 'a',
        name : 'Andrew'
    },{
        id: 'b',
        name : 'Barry'
    },{
        id : 'c',
        name: 'Caroline'
    }
]
```

preferably using vanilla js, but I use lodash in my application so I have access to that library.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: `Object.values(o);`

Comment: @ASDFGerte that's perfect, thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How might I extract the property values of a JavaScript object into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718777/how-might-i-extract-the-property-values-of-a-javascript-object-into-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const data = {
  a: { id: 'a', name: 'Andrew' },
  b: { id: 'b', name: 'Barry' },
  c: { id: 'c', name: 'Caroline' }
};

const result = Object.values(data);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```js
const input = {
    'a' : {
        id: ' a',
        name : 'Andrew'
    },
    'b' : {
        id : 'b',
        name : 'Barry'
    },
    'c' : {
        id: 'c',
        name: 'Caroline'
    }
};

 
const output = Object.values(input);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You don't need the `map` in there. `Object.values` is sufficient on its own.

Comment: What’s the point in adding a „map“? Object.values already gives us an array with the values, your call to map does nothing than pass the values from that array on to another one

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combination for example:

```js
const data = {
    'a' : {
        id: 'a',
        name : 'Andrew'
    },
    'b' : {
        id : 'b',
        name : 'Barry'
    },
    'c' : {
        id: 'c',
        name: 'Caroline'
    }
};

const result = Object.entries(data).map(e => e[1]);

console.log(result);
```

Or you can use `Object.values()` for shorter version.

I hope this helps!

Comment: `Object.values()` is shorter :)

Comment: @Andy That's correct, just extended my answer with that comment, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by map through the `Object.keys()`

```js
const data = {
    'a': {
        id: ' a',
        name : 'Andrew'
    },
    'b': {
        id : 'b',
        name : 'Barry'
    },
    'c': {
        id: 'c',
        name: 'Caroline'
    }
};

const arr = Object.keys(data).map(v => data[v]);

console.log(arr);
```